# Split Audio File with python Librosa

Tags: python, librosa, audio-analysis

After doing split in an audio file with Librosa, I want to know how to obtain the resultant fragments in mp3 files[See audio image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV9CK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you just open individual files like

```
    fragment1 = open("x.mp3", "a")
    fragment2 = open("y.mp3", "a")
```

and then write to each of those using what you have as variables?